# How to: In bash print a value from a key/value pair

Tags: bash

I need to print only the `900` in this line: `auth required pam_faillock.so preauth silent deny=3 unlock_time=604800 fail_interval=900`

*However, this line will not always be in this order.*

I need to find out how to print the value after the `=`. 
I will need to do this for `unlock_time` and `fail_interval`

I have been searching all night for something that will work exactly for me and cannot find it. I have been toying around with sed and awk and have not nailed this down yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's define your string:

```
s='auth required pam_faillock.so preauth silent deny=3 unlock_time=604800 fail_interval=900'
```

Using awk:

```
$ printf %s "$s" | awk -F= '$1=="fail_interval"{print $2}' RS=' '
900
```

Or:

```
$ printf %s "$s" | awk -F= '$1=="unlock_time"{print $2}' RS=' '
604800
```

#### How it works

Awk divides its input into records.  We tell it to use a space as the record separator.  Each record is divided into fields.  We tell awk to use `=` as the field separator.  In more detail:

- `printf %s "$s"`

  This prints the string.  `printf` is safer than `echo` in cases where the string might begin with `-`.
- `-F=`

  This tells awk to use `=` as the field separator.
- `$1=="fail_interval" {print $2}`

  If the first field is `fail_interval`, then we tell awk to print the second field.
- `RS=' '`

  This tells awk to use a space as the record separator.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `sed` for this

**Command**

```
echo "...stuff.... unlock_time=604800 fail_interval=900" | sed -E '
s/^.*unlock_time=([[:digit:]]*).*fail_interval=([[:digit:]]*).*$/\1 \2/'
```

**Output**

```
604800 900
```

**Notes**

- The `(..)` in `sed` is used for selections.
- `[[:digit:]]*` or `0-9` is used to match any number of digits
- The `\1` and `\2` is used to replace the matched stuff, in order.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this.

```
unlock_time=$(echo "auth required pam_faillock.so preauth silent deny=3 unlock_time=604800 fail_interval=900" | awk -F'unlock_time=' '{print $2}' | awk '{print $1}')

echo "$unlock_time"

fail_interval=$(echo "auth required pam_faillock.so preauth silent deny=3 unlock_time=604800 fail_interval=900" | awk -F'fail_interval=' '{print $2}' | awk '{print $1}')

echo "$fail_interval"
```

Answer (score 0):

Given an `input` variable:

```
input="auth required pam_faillock.so preauth silent deny=3 unlock_time=604800 fail_interval=900"
```

With GNU grep:

```
$ grep -oP 'fail_interval=\K([0-9]*)' <<< "$input"
900
$ grep -oP 'unlock_time=\K([0-9]*)' <<< "$input"
604800
```